# Full-width vertical responsive triangle with transparent background

Tags: html, css, shapes

I have seen hundreds of posts on stack overflow about triangles.
Most of the triangles needed are small and horizontal, but I could not find what I need.

I need a triangle that is:

- Vertical
- Full width
- Left to right
- Leftside is full height of parent
- Responsive
- Transparent above and below the triangle

By researching the posts on stackoverflow, I came up with two examples:

**Case 1:** Responsive, but not transparent top/bottom:

```css
.element {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(
      to top left,
      black,
      black 50%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,
    rgba(0,0,0,0)) left center no-repeat,linear-gradient(
    to bottom left, 
    black, 
    black 50%, 
    #007bff 50%, 
    #007bff
  )  left center no-repeat;
  background-size:200% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the background is black. If I change this to transparent, it will not work, because the bottom part is overwritten by black and if I make it transparent, the blue will shine through (of course).

**Case 2:** Transparent, but not responsive:

```css
.element {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}


.overlay2 {
  background-color:transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  border-left: solid 700px rgb(255,255,255);
  border-bottom: solid 150px transparent;
  border-top: solid 150px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="overlay2"></div>
</div>
```

The problem here is the border-left. I have to insert a size in pixels. This is not responsive and thus not acceptable.

Is there any way to do what I want to do without using JavaScript?

Comment: Have you considered using SVG element or does that have to be done in CSS?

Comment: SVG is perfectly fine, but I never used it, so I haven't looked into it yet.
Can I create a background overlay with it ?

Comment: Also supported on IE? I need to at least support IE 11, preferably IE 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use responsive SVG element for overlay, like this:

```css
.element {
  background-color:lightgreen;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.overlay3 {
  height: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
<svg class="overlay3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 50 50" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="100%" height="50">
  <polygon points="0,0 0,50 50,25" style="fill:#ffffff"/>
</svg>
```

You don't have to worry about browser support, it's VERY widely supported standard. http://caniuse.com/#search=svg

Comment: YOU - ARE - AWESOME. Why couldn't I find that solution. This is just what I need! Thank you so much :D